# simulating HTTP POST handling using Angular Tutorial web-server script

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to develop AngularJS applicatino using the Angular tutorial web-server script.
Is it possible or smart to use it for development only scenario ?

I want to be able to develop and test my Angular application without relying on the real server and real database, that's the reason I'm asking this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about the tutorial web-server script.

When it comes to your situation, though, your best bet is to abstract away your data managing processes. In other words, you can make a set of services that take care of loading and saving your data. You could have methods like `book.save()` or `book.fetch()`.

Then in `save()` and `fetch()` you can return or insert an object literal or call for a JSON file.

Assuming that your product will be running on JSON data, you should be able to write another set of model services that call JSON data from the server rather any that you've hard written in the code or in a *.json file.